# Flutter windows build release - can't access log file

Tags: windows, flutter, logging, build

I am developing a flutter windows app.  I use the popular logger package (https://pub.dev/packages/logger) to log info throughout my app, and log to a file call app.log in the root folder of my application.  This all works fine when running during development.  I can see and open the generated log file:

```
final logger = Logger(
  filter: null,
  printer: PrettyPrinter(
    methodCount: 1,
    errorMethodCount: 6,
    lineLength: 120,
    colors: false,
    printEmojis: false,
    printTime: true,
  ),
  output: AppFileOutput(),
);

class AppFileOutput extends LogOutput {
  AppFileOutput();

  late File file;

  @override
  void output(OutputEvent event) async {
    late File file = File(Directory.current.path + r'\app.log');
    
    for (var line in event.lines) {
      await file.writeAsString("${line.toString()}\n", mode: FileMode.writeOnlyAppend);
      debugPrint(line); //print to console as well
    }
  }
}
```

Problem is when i build and run my flutter windows app, the application folder structure is different.  From what i can tell, i can no longer see or access this log file anymore.  Where the app.exe is, there is no expected log file.

How can i log information so that the end user can access this file for debug/help reasons wonce the app is released?

Answer (score 1):

You should use something like the [path_provider](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider) to find out a safe location for you to store files.
On Windows that would typically be one of the `%AppData%` directories, but on MacOs or Linux these would be entirely different.
`path_provider` supports all platforms, so it *just* works.

Comment: Thanks mate...in the end i changed logging packages at it started working.

Answer (score 0):

```
final logger = Logger(
  filter: ProductionFilter(),
  printer: PrettyPrinter(
    methodCount: 1,
    errorMethodCount: 6,
    lineLength: 120,
    colors: false,
    printEmojis: false,
    printTime: true,
  ),
  output: AppFileOutput(),
);
```

filter: ProductionFilter, it can work normally in release mode